# Laravel not setting the XSRF-Token cookie on the live server

Tags: angular, laravel, x-xsrf-token

I created an app with Laravel 5.7.16 and Angular2 and everything works fine in my localhost.

However, on the live server, I got a "419 error" when submitting post requests. After some research, I concluded that this would likely be due to an issue with the XSRF-TOKEN. Then, when comparing what was going on in my localhost and on the live server, I noticed that the live server is not setting the XSRF-TOKEN cookie on the initial request.

I am not explicitly setting the XSRF-TOKEN on my Angular2 HTTP post request, but from what I understood, Angular2 does this automatic, as long as a XSRF-TOKEN cookie is initially setting by the server side application.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this?

Edit: I have just tried adding one of my application post routes to the $except array of VerifyCsrfToken, and that works. However, this is more of a workaround, rather than the actual solution.
What is interesting is that, after executing the "allowed" route, the XSRF-TOKEN is returned, and all other routes work. I think this reinforces the idea that the issue is that the XSRF-TOKEN is not being returned in the initial application load. Why would that be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I had the same problem on my local machine. 
XSRF-TOKEN cookie was not getting set on browser. I tried the following steps and problem was solved.

- Give permission to folders. `sudo chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache`
- Clear config and application cache.  `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your Laravel caches

php artisan cache:clear

And also clear your browser cookies to make sure there isn't a session stored already?

Comment: Hi @Kiksy. I tried clearing the Laravel cache but it did not work. If I used the same browser I use to test the application in my localhost, the cookies set by the localhost work in terms of getting past the XSRF-TOKEN check. However, if I use a different browser, then the XSRF-TOKEN does not get set.

I know the workarounds of using api routes instead of web routes or putting the post route in the $except array of VerifyCsrfToken would work. However, I would like to avoid workarounds...